# Simple and right way to link and add columns to database tables, database design

Tags: sql, database, database-design, ms-access

I have following tables.

**Product** with following attributes:

- ProductID  << ID of the product
- ProductName << name of product
- ProductPrice << Price of product

**Recipe** with following attributes:

- RecipeID << index of Recipe
- ProductID << multiple productID and are/ can be duplicate
- ingredientID << multiple ingredientID but are unique for specific productID
- productAsIngredientID << sometimes product itself can act as an ingredient. eg. Bun (it can be sold independently as a bun or can be added to Recipe of Burger)
- ingredientAmount<< Quantity (double/int)

**Ingredients** with following attribute:

- ingredientID << it is the list of raw ingredients, eg (flour)
- ingredientName
- ingredientUnitType << type of unit it holds (eg. gm, ml, etc)

Sampel database for the tables above:

PRODUCT:

```
|   ProductID    |    ProductName    |   ProductPrice   | 

       12             Bun                     1.5
       15             Ham Burger              5
       13             Chicken Burger          7
```

INGREDIENT:

```
|    ingredientID    |      ingredientName         |   ingredientUnitType   |          

         1                   Salt                           gm
         2                   Yeast                          gm
         3                   Refined Wheat Flour            gm
         4                   Milk                           ml
         5                   Chicken Meat                   gm
         6                   Onion                          gm
         7                   Tomatoes                       gm
```

RECIPE:

```
| RecipeID | ProductID | ingredientID  |  productAsIngredientID  |  ingredientAmount  |

     1          13                               12                         1
     2          13           5                                             20
     3          13           6                                              7
     4          13           7                                             10
     5          12           1                                              5
     6          12           2                                              2
     7          12           3                                             10
     8          .            .
     9          .            .
```

in Recipe Table, ProductID can not be equal to productAsIngredientID in a same row. But in table Recipe, productID and productAsIngredientID both links to Product.ProductID.

However there is a problem in linking these the above two tables with productID. If I linked them, none of them can have null values or any values that is not in ingredients or Product Table.

I am using Microsoft Access (MDB) as a database 
Please suggest me a right way to get this done. How can I organize the Product item itself as a type of ingredient itself.

Comment: Short answer: Google "many to many relationship access", because you will probably need several "link tables" which contains the Id columns from other tables. I.e. The table **Product_to_recipe** with columns **RecipeId** and **ProductId** and so on for the other many-to-many relationships. You will then join all the tables in you query, when querying. **SELECT * FROM Recipe INNER JOIN Product_to_recipe ON Recipe.RecipeId = Product_to_recipe.RecipeId** which will give you all products related to a recipe.

Comment: Is this a [bill of materials (BOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_materials)? Also, have you looked for existing software that meets your requirements ("Buy, don't build")?

Comment: @onedaywhen: Bad answer! Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is how to create many-to-many relationships between tables.

This is done by a separate "link table" which contains the Id from two other tables (and in your case we will add another column to the ingredient link table, the amount.

So the schema would look like this (I prefer attributes without the tablename as prefix):

**Product**

- Id
- ProductName
- Price
- Unit

**Ingredient**

- Id
- IngredientName
- Unit

**Recipe**

- Id
- RecipeName

**RecipeProducts**

- RecipeId (foreign key: Recipe.Id)
- ProductId (foreign key: Product.Id)
- Amount

**RecipeIngredients**

- RecipeId (foreing key: Recipe.Id)
- IngredientId (foreign key: Ingredient.Id)
- Amount

That's how I would normally layout the schema, but I am not that familiar with Access.

This is what I get from the access query wizard to get all Ingredients for a recipe

```
SELECT Ingredient.IngredientName, RecipeIngredients.Amount, Ingredient.Unit
FROM Ingredient 
INNER JOIN RecipeIngredients 
ON Ingredient.[ID] = RecipeIngredients.[IngredientId] 
WHERE RecipeIngredients.RecipeId = 1;
```

Not the best SQL and I suppose someone can provide a smarter way to get both products and ingredients for a recipe.

the **productAsIngredientId** should not be necessary, since when a product is a part of a recipe, it will be an ingredient, right? otherwise you need to change your table names to something more logical.

Comment: Good point on the separation of "Products" and "ingredients" -- bun may be an ingredient but equally flour is a product -- you by it by the pound. To further complicate the issue the poster is actually solving the wrong problem, the, real problem is that a "recipe" can also be an "ingredient" as in "bolognese sauce" and "bechemal sauce" are both ingredients of a classic lasagne.

Comment: @JamesAnderson: Bun is a product and may be an ingredient, but flour is not a product its clearly lies on ingredient's list. 

Yes a recipe can also be an ingredient, here, the the whole recipe lies inside a product. Eg. The recipe of bun lies on the product Bun

Comment: Would be very helpful to get the whole picture, i.e. what will the system be used for? If you want a recipe to be part of another recipe you probably need another linktable named **RecipeRecipes** or something like that (what ever naming makes sense to you). But then I guess, based on the context, that you would rather name the Recipe containing other recipes something else, like a Menu, Dish or something, thus creating another table called **Dish**, but it depends on the use of your app.

Comment: I imagine the OP is aiming at a shopping list, so bun may be something you buy or make, similarly Bechamel sauce. Product might run "SoSo Co makes a good enough sauce" and "See recipe for Bechamel to make your own". Perhaps StackExchange cookery needs a code section :)

Comment: @Remou: you are right. Bun is something customer buy (as a product), and it is also something we add in other product like Ham Burger (as a ingredient)

Comment: Products and ingredients could easily be in the same table, using a flag column to separate them. It's not clear what the 'price' column in the 'products' table is - the selling price? It would be worth adding a 'cost price' field to this table - then one could easily see how much a recipe would cost to make!

Comment: @Newman: Yes, these are good points, I guess it's up to the poster to decide, since he know what the system will do. I guess the OP should get a solid understanding of what the system should do and start on the drawing board before implementing anything. Object model might be the correct name for it?

Comment: @No'amNewman: Obviosuly LUC and SP will be there I don't think it was necessary to include my whole database here.

Comment: @Sverker84: I have properly addressed my problem, I know what I want. And I am just asking for the correct way to do it. There are always alternatives for any solution, "better alternatives".

Comment: @Sverker84: Thank you for your hints. 

One to one was what I needed, not many to many.
I wanted to replace Recipe.RecipeName with Recipe.productID. Hence Recipe table will contain Recipe ID and the product ID to which it is assigned.

To get the recipe I had to setup two queries (up to my knowledge in access), one for fetching Recipe with ingredients and another for product as Ingredient. I didn't find any good solution to to mix up the multiple column in to one. However, this is out of scope of this thread.

Comment: Good that you solved it. As for addressing the problem, this is what I find myself doing wrong many times. To eager to start programming i guess :) Didn't mean that as a direct suggestion to you, but rather as a general tips for anyone reading :)

Comment: @useer995387 -- strip away the foodie touches and this becomes a classic "Bill of Materials" database. Long and painful experience has shown that there is no point in separating things you buy specially to make a particular product (e.g. an alternator) from stuff you have in the warehouse (e.g. screws) as that decision belongs to purchasing and changes over time. The tough problem where common assemblies (e.g. a fusebox) appear in the BOM for other products.